# How to use "what does x mean?" structure with long noun phrases?

Tags: questions, wh-questions

If I want to make a sentence like that: "What does a cat mean?", It's easy.

But how can I make a question with long noun phrases?
My sample phrase: "a type of cat with long-haired ears"

I tried to make it by "what does it mean when [phrase]?" and "what does it mean that [phrase]?".

But it seemed weird to me, I think that the two structure above are used with sentences that have verb. (For exm:"What does it mean that a cat has long haired ears?" <- it's ok, but "What does it mean that a type of cat with long-haired ears?"<- this is weird)

Comment: There are tons of questions with long noun phrases. But what you are asking contains no "long noun phrase".

Comment: Your questions are unclear. Are you asking, "What does **the word** cat mean?" [Answer: a feline.] Are you asking, "What does a cat mean **when it meows**?" [Answer: it could be asking for attention.] Think of "means" as "intends" or "demonstrates", or "indicates". The examples are also incorrect: "What does it mean that a cat has long haired ears?" does not make sense -- there is no intention, no meaning, no indication of something, in having long ears. "What does it mean if my nose is running?" [That might be an *indication* of an allergy or cold.] "What does it mean that the statue has long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure this can get confusing.  For short phrases, you can highlight the fact you are asking about a phrase by including that information.

> What does the phrase, "Thank goodness it's Friday!" mean?

In speech you would use intonation and pauses to separate the phrase from the rest of the sentence. In written English you should use quote marks, even with single words:  What does "cat" mean?

For even longer phrases, use reference

> Consider the phrase, "a type of cat with long-haired ears".  What does it mean?  [or "What does that mean?"]

Using "when" means you are asking about the situation, not the words.  Saying "What does it mean when a cat has long-haired ears?" is similar to asking "What causes a cat to have long-haired ears?" or "What are the consequences of a cat having long-haired ears?"